# Div not expanding properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

Whenever I set the div width to 100%, and I add new elements to it, it expands over the screen border.
When I set the div to the pixel value, it works fine, but it won't look proper on two different screen resolutions.
So the thing I want is to have a div which would fit the edge of the screen and expand properly.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/272p06ng/4/

Spam on Add Tab a few times to see the problem. Then look for `.l_tabs` in CSS and read the comment. I believe that the problem is in the parent classes of `l_tabs`.

Div with % value behaves like this:

[image]

Div with pixel value shows the behavior I want:

[image]

Tabs Construction:

```
 <div class="l_tabs">
  <div>
    <ul id="myTab1" class="nav nav-tabs bordered">
     <li class="tab-add"></li>
     <li class="contentTab active "></li>
     <li.....></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.l_tabs {
    background: #474544 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: block;
    height: 57px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%; /* 1st picture */
    width: 1370px; /* second picture */
}
.l_tabs > div {
    background-color: #474544;
    height: 57px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 100%;
}
.l_tabs > div > ul {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And there are some parent wrappers with also width 100%.

> EDIT:Adding `position:absolute` to `l.tabs`
>   fixed the problem.

Comment: Link to jsfiddle please (working code is easier to fix, really); max-width: 100% + overflow: hidden (with your already created scroll bar) could be an answer -> try it

Comment: Will complete static version be ok for you?

Comment: Here you have working static version - https://jsfiddle.net/272p06ng/7/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120797/discussion-between-stefan-stefko-and-masterfan).

Comment: You should post the solution _as an answer_, together with an explanation of why it solved your problem, if possible. You can then accept your own answer after a waiting period of 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.l_tabs {
  height: 57px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #474544 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!